# "temporary failure in name resolution" installing Notepad++ snap

Tags: software-installation, snap

I want to install Notepad++ with commands but there is an error:

```
error:cannot install "notepad-plus-plus":post
      https://api.snapcraft.io/v2/snaps/refresh: dial tcp: lookup api.snapcraft.io:
      temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to AU. Could you please expand on your question? What is the exact set of commands you are using, and what are the exact errors you are receiving? Please [edit your post](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1183597/edit) With that information.

Comment: hi! thanks,i just used this command:sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the temporary DNS failures described in bugs 1804487, 1727237, and 1805027.  Assuming you haven't done anything to the default DNS setup, I found that adding the package libnss-resolve fixed my issues.  That package rewrites the /etc/nsswitch.conf file to better handle certain situations.

```
sudo apt-get install libnss-resolve
```